# Faster serialization / deserialization of object data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, serialization, redux, server-side-rendering

I'm doing server-side rendering using and React/Redux.

To pass Redux data to the front end, I'm serializing it to JSON in a script tag thats hydrated on the client in the head:

```
<script>window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=${JSON.stringify(store.getState())};</script>
```

Some problems with this:

- the state is extremely large (unfortunately "just make it smaller" isn't a solution), meaning the client has to download a significant amount of data
- de-serialization time on the client is non-trivial
- since its in a script tag, the browser blocks waiting for it to load.  Some of this is unavoidable since the state impacts the UI

Is there a faster and/or more compact way to serialize and re-serialize Javascript object hierarchy (blobs, proto-buffs, etc) that fits this use-case?

Comment: It depends on the kind of data but unfortunately there might be nothing for you really beating the heavily optimized JSON parsing. If you want to test by yourself you could add messagepack which is more alike JSON than protobuf. Lazy loading & complex cachings are usually the best solution